# MACOS OpenGL

Tags: homebrew, macos, opengl

У меня, наверно, 2 вопроса, но они вроде как связаны.

1. Я пытаюсь разобраться, с чего начать изучение opengl, но чтобы все используемые библиотеки были наиболее популярны. 
   На http://www.opengl-tutorial.org вроде как неплохой туториал, но на маке у меня проблемы с исполнением этого кода и **там написано, что в mac os какие-то проблемы с opengl 3.3, это все еще актуально?**
2. В общем, я что-то пытался делать, уже не помню, оно писало, что, мол, какие-то ошибки с битностью, но я переустановил glew и glfw на 32 бит, и не очень помогло.
   Я обновил свой мак, и теперь все стало еще хуже.

Например, я сделал:

```
brew install glfw3
```

потом делаю

```
#include <GL/glfw.h>
```

И оно его не находит.

Вот то, что дает find:

```
$ sudo find /usr -iname '*glfw*' -print
Password:
/usr/local/Cellar/glfw3
/usr/local/Cellar/glfw3/3.1/include/GLFW
/usr/local/Cellar/glfw3/3.1/include/GLFW/glfw3.h
/usr/local/Cellar/glfw3/3.1/include/GLFW/glfw3native.h
/usr/local/Cellar/glfw3/3.1/lib/cmake/glfw
/usr/local/Cellar/glfw3/3.1/lib/cmake/glfw/glfw3Config.cmake
/usr/local/Cellar/glfw3/3.1/lib/cmake/glfw/glfw3ConfigVersion.cmake
/usr/local/Cellar/glfw3/3.1/lib/cmake/glfw/glfwTargets-none.cmake
/usr/local/Cellar/glfw3/3.1/lib/cmake/glfw/glfwTargets.cmake
/usr/local/Cellar/glfw3/3.1/lib/libglfw3.3.1.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/glfw3/3.1/lib/libglfw3.3.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/glfw3/3.1/lib/libglfw3.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/glfw3/3.1/lib/pkgconfig/glfw3.pc
/usr/local/include/GLFW
/usr/local/lib/libglfw3.3.1.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libglfw3.3.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libglfw3.dylib
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/glfw3.pc
/usr/local/Library/Formula/glfw2.rb
/usr/local/Library/Formula/glfw3.rb
/usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/glfw3
/usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-versions/glfw2.rb
/usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-versions/glfw3.rb
/usr/local/opt/glfw3
```

Если я делаю так:

```
\#include <GL/usr/local/Cellar/glfw3/3.1/include/GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

получаю

```
ld: library not found for -lglfw3
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[Finished in 0.7s with exit code 1]
```

Компилю вот так (билд из саблайма):

```
g++ '${file}'  -lglfw3 -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -framework Cocoa -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'
```

Все то же самое для glew, например.

Пробовал уже сто раз все удалять и устанавливать, но бесполезно

Я подозреваю, что brew как-то залинкил криво, поэтому оно не ищется, но я пробовал какие-то скрипты, которые находил, и они, к сожалению, не помогали.

В общем, как мне сделать так, чтобы было все как у людей?

Comment: @Влад Жуков, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Советую попробовать по изучать http://nehe.gamedev.net/

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал ознакомиться с документацией от Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/opengl/

Проблем с OpenGL 3.3 не встречал. Современные маки работают с версиями 3.3 и 4.1. В своей работе встречал различия в основном при написании вертексного шейдера при использовании EXT_separate_shader_objects, который уже входит в состав OpenGL

Answer (score 1):

Суда по ошибки, ваш линковщик не может найти библиотеку libglfw3.a. Судя по вашим файлам у вас её нет. Попробуйте поменять -lglfw3 на -lglfw. Также ваш линковщик должен знать где лежит ваша библиотека. Также посмотрите вот эту статью: http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build.html#build_link_xcode